# Python Requests from SOAP API - Task exited with return code -9

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

**Requirement**: To extract data from SOAP API and write it to CSV file

**Issue**:  My code works well until about 76th responses. After this, it throws an error as "Task exited with return code -9". I guess it is some sort of buffer issue, but I have no idea how to fix this issue.

**Question**: How to avoid memory issues?

**Code explanation:**

1. Calls the function `fetch_audit_log_report_data` which calls the function `fetch_audit_log_report_page_number` at first to get the number of pages to be looped
2. Then for each page incremental, it extracts data and writes it to a final CSV file

**Code**:

```
def populate_xml_tags(record_list, main_xml):
    list = json.loads(main_xml.getElementsByTagName("ReportData")[0].childNodes[0].data)
    list.extend(record_list)
    main_xml.getElementsByTagName("ReportData")[0].childNodes[0].data = json.dumps(list)
    return main_xml

def fetch_audit_log_report_page_number(file_name, user, password, as_of_date, url, start_date, end_date, page_size, page_number):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        auditlog_filled = audit_log_report.format(
            user=user, password=password, as_of_date=as_of_date, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date,
            page_size=page_size, page_number=page_number)
        encoded_u = base64.b64encode(auditlog_filled.encode()).decode()
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % encoded_u, 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
        logger.info('Sending request to API for AuditLogReport Data')
        send_query_response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=auditlog_filled)
        send_query_response.raise_for_status()
        response_data = send_query_response.text.encode('utf8')
        main_xml = minidom.parseString(response_data)
        if len(minidom.parseString(response_data).getElementsByTagName("NumberOfPages")[0].childNodes) > 0:
            if main_xml != "":
                if len(minidom.parseString(response_data).getElementsByTagName("NumberOfPages")[0].childNodes) > 0:
                    return json.loads(minidom.parseString(response_data).getElementsByTagName("NumberOfPages")[0].childNodes[0].data)
            else:
                logger.info(f"No Data pulled from AuditLogReport API")
                return False
        else:
            logger.info(f"No Data pulled from AuditLogReport API")
            return False

def fetch_audit_log_report_data(file_name, user, password, as_of_date, url, start_date, end_date):
    number_of_pages = fetch_audit_log_report_page_number(
        file_name, user, password, as_of_date, url, start_date, end_date, 1000, 1)
    main_xml = ""
    for page in range(number_of_pages):
        logger.info(f'{page+1} : {number_of_pages}')
        with requests.Session() as session:
            auditlog_filled = audit_log_report.format(
                user=user, password=password, as_of_date=as_of_date, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date,
                page_size=1000, page_number=page+1)
            encoded_u = base64.b64encode(auditlog_filled.encode()).decode()
            headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % encoded_u,
                    'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
            logger.info('Sending request to API for AuditLogReport Data')
            send_query_response = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=auditlog_filled)
            send_query_response.raise_for_status()
            response_data = send_query_response.text.encode('utf8')
            if len(minidom.parseString(response_data).getElementsByTagName("ReportData")[0].childNodes) > 0:
                if main_xml == "":
                    main_xml = minidom.parseString(response_data)
                else:
                    for item in minidom.parseString(response_data).getElementsByTagName("ReportData"):
                        main_xml = populate_xml_tags(json.loads(item.childNodes[0].data), main_xml)
            else:
                logger.info(f"No Data pulled from AuditLogReport API")
                continue
        if main_xml != "":
            with open(file_name, "w") as f:
                f.write(main_xml.toxml().replace("&quot;", '"'))
                f.flush()
                f.close()
        else:
            logger.info(f"No Data pulled from AuditLogReport API")
            continue
    if main_xml != "":
        return True
    else:
        return False



log_report =\
    """<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <AuthHeader xmlns="EnIP">
            <Username>{user}</Username>
            <Password>{password}</Password>
        </AuthHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <GetFilteredCustomReport xmlns="L_EIP">
            <ownerId>1</ownerId>
            <customReportFilterRequestDto>
                <ReportName>LgReport</ReportName>
                <Filters>
                    <FilterItem>
                        <Key>Date</Key>
                        <Value>2020-08-06</Value>
                        <Operation>GTEQ</Operation>
                    </FilterItem>
                    <FilterItem>
                        <Key>Date</Key>
                        <Value>2020-08-07</Value>
                        <Operation>LTEQ</Operation>
                    </FilterItem>
                </Filters>
                <Pager>
                    <PageSize>{page_size}</PageSize>
                    <PageNumber>{page_number}</PageNumber>
                </Pager>
                <TimeoutSeconds>1000</TimeoutSeconds>
            </customReportFilterRequestDto>
        </GetFilteredCustomReport>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Updated the original post